# Verifying ownership of AWS route 53 domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I purchased a domain through aws route 53 being the DNS provider. Now, I would like to transfer my domain to google Firebase.

In order to do this transfer, I am being given a google-site-verification txt record to add to my DNS provider in order to verify ownership, but I don't know how to do this. The record is type: text, host: "mydomain.com", and value: "google-site-verification-etc.."

I have tried adding a record set with the google verification code as the value to my aws domain's hosted zone, but I am getting the error, `The record set could not be saved because:
- The Value field contains invalid characters or is in an invalid format.`, because the code is not a url. What am I supposed to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a TXT record type, pointed to google-site-verification-etc..

P.S. The error you see depends on what record type you tried to add e.g. if A record it means the value is not an IP address, if CNAME the value is not a hostname.